# Collapsible comments in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the latest Drupal 7.2 core and I have no idea how to solve my problem. I'd like to collapse all nodes comments (there's lots of them) and expose them for the user when he presses 'show comments'. I know it has something to do with the fieldsets (or maybe I'm wrong), but where, what and how ?

Every helpful answer will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope there's a solution for this. I really need help.

Comment: Maybe putting the comments into panel and set its style to collapsible would work, but I don't want to loose my actual comments style (standard theme style). What should I do?

Comment: THIS could be a solution, but there's no D7 port here:
http://drupal.org/node/94035

Comment: I think you could benefit from a jQuery approach, just hiding and showing the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a begging private message to one of the contributors and he posted a working solution for collapsible comments in D7 - http://drupal.org/node/94035#comment-4674734

Answer (score 1):

So i tried a bunch of ways as suggested [here](http://drupal.org/node/94035).

The thing I ended up doing since I was trying to basically just put all the `comments` stuff into a collapsible fieldset is outlined here:

1. Go into the `Content Type -> Manage Display`.
2. Create an empty fieldset called something like `Comments` (You'll need `fieldset`/`fieldcollection` modules)
3. Once you have the group, grab the `field_groupname` for later use in code.

In your theme's `template.php`, or whereever you have the render arrays you'll have something like this to basically add the "comments" object into the group fieldset you just created.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook){
    $tempField = null;

    // Copy the comments / comment form into a variable.
    $tempField = $vars['content']['comments']; 

    // Rename some of the labels, use the markup
    $tempField['#title'] = "DMS URL";
    $tempField['#field_name'] = "field_comments";
    $tempField[0]['#markup'] = $vars['content']['comments'];

    // Add it into the group (fieldset/group name you copied)
    $vars['content']['group_commentsgroup']['field_comments'] = $tempField;
}
```

This will basically add your comments markup into an empty fieldset/group you created using node's manage display using `fieldset`/`fieldcollection`. Also, I was using `ajax_comments` for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a tip than an answer to your problem, but our website stopped using Drupal comments since they were too basic and moved to use the free service called [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com)

Comment: Great tip, thanks. But I'd rather stay with those basic comments which fits clients needs. Anyway thanks - nice tip for the future.

Comment: I was able to find this with a bit of Googling though, could be quite easily modified to work with D7 http://drupal.org/node/94035

Comment: Yes, seen that, but there's no solution for Drupal 7. What should I change and where put this to get collapsible comments ?

Answer (score 0):

After a looong time of searching For Individual Collapsible comments I found a solution, where you can put your comment replies in an individual collapsible fieldset. :)

Below code in script.js
Include the js in .info file as scripts[] = js/script.js

(function($) {$(function() {
    // Hurry up and hide the comments and its replies, if present.  In most browsers, this

```
$('.indented').hide();

// The Comment section will be turned into a toggle to
//     open/close the comments
$('.comment').addClass('closed').bind('click', function() {
  var $self = $(this),
      $form = $self.siblings('.indented'),
      speed = 250; // speed of animation, change to suit, larger = slower

  if ($self.hasClass('open')) {
    $self.addClass('transition').removeClass('open');
    $form.hide(speed, function() {
      $self.addClass('closed').removeClass('transition');
    });
  }
  else {
    $self.addClass('transition').removeClass('closed');
    $form.show(speed, function() {
      $self.addClass('open').removeClass('transition');
    });
  }
});
```

});     })(jQuery);